# How to skip blank rows in a csv file during import in Laravel

Tags: laravel, csv, import

During the import of a CSV file, my import function creates a database record for every row of the import file. This means that if a user has left a blank row in the file then the import process creates a blank record in the database. How does one develop it so that the importer identifies blank/null rows in the CSV file, skips those blank/null rows, and only creates a record and imports a row if the row contains data?

Here is the Controller for the Import function:

```
public function process(Request $request)
    {
        $filename = $request->input('filename', false);
        $path = storage_path('app/csv_import/'.$filename);

        $hasHeader = $request->input('hasHeader', false);
        $isAddingNewReligiousBackground = $request->input('is_adding_new_religious_background', false);

        $fields = $request->input('fields', false);
        $fields = array_flip(array_filter($fields));

        $modelName = $request->input('modelName', false);
        $model = 'App\\'.$modelName;

        $reader = new SpreadsheetReader($path);
        $insert = [];
        $update = [];
        $tags = [];

        $team_id = $request->input('church_id');
        $custom_fields = CustomField::where('created_by_team_id', $team_id)->get();

        foreach ($reader as $key => $row) {
            if ($hasHeader && $key == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            $tmp = [];
            $meta = [];
            foreach ($fields as $header => $k) {
                $tmp[$header] = $row[$k];
            }

            $tmp['created_by_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
            $tmp['created_by_team_id'] = $team_id;
            $tmp['created_at'] = now();

            if ($modelName == 'Interest') {
                $this->translateReligiousBackgroud($tmp, $isAddingNewReligiousBackground);
                $meta = $this->processInterestMeta($tmp, $custom_fields);
                $existing = Interest::matchingInterest((object) $tmp, $request->input('church_id'));
                if ($existing) {
                    $update[] = $existing;
                    $tagsArr = array_filter((array) $request->input('interest_tags'));
                    foreach (\DB::table('interest_tag')->where('interest_id', $existing->id)->get() as $tag) {
                        $tagsArr[] = $tag->tag_id;
                    }
                    $existing->interest_tags()->sync(array_filter($tagsArr));
                    if (! empty($meta)) {
                        $existing->syncMeta($meta);
                    }
                } else {
                    $tmp['meta'] = $meta;
                    $insert[] = $tmp;
                }
            } else {
                $insert[] = $tmp;
            }
        }

        $for_insert = array_chunk($insert, 10000); // this was 100, but the chunking was causing the system to only import the first 100 records, even though the success message said it imported all of them - LW 1/25/2019
        foreach ($for_insert as $insert_item) {
            if ($modelName == 'Interest') {
                foreach ($insert_item as $item) {
                    $interest = new $model;
                    foreach ($item as $field => $value) {
                        if ($field != 'meta') {
                            $interest->$field = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    $interest->created_by_id = auth()->user()->id;
                    $interest->created_by_team_id = $request->input('church_id');
                    $interest->save();

                    // For some reason, created_by_team_id was null on initial save, do it again
                    $interest->created_by_team_id = $request->input('church_id');
                    $interest->save();

                    // deal with tags
                    $interest->interest_tags()->sync(array_filter((array) $request->input('interest_tags')));

                    // deal with custom fields
                    if (! empty($item['meta'])) {
                        $interest->syncMeta($item['meta']);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $model::insert($insert_item);
            }
        }
        $rows = count($insert);
        $updates = count($update);
        $table = Str::plural($modelName);

        File::delete($path);

        $redirect = $request->input('redirect', false);

        return redirect()->to($redirect)->with('message', trans(($updates > 0 ? 'global.app_imported_rows_to_table_with_updates' : 'global.app_imported_rows_to_table'),
            ['rows' => $rows, 'updates' => $updates, 'table' => $table]
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just check whether fields aren't empty in a foreach loop where you're inserting to the DB?

Comment: Yes, thank you, sorry for being unclear. That is what I am attempting to do but it hasn't worked for me that is what I am hoping to get assistance on.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is the proper way and I hope someone comes along and gives the proper answer but this here is my dirty hack. In my dataset, I have a column for lastname and all the records to have any functional purpose must have a last name so I put an -if- statement `if (!empty($interest['lastname']))` checking that the 'lastname' not be empty before save.

```
         $for_insert = array_chunk($insert, 10000); // this was 100, but the chunking was causing the system to only import the first 100 records, even though the success message said it imported all of them - LW 1/25/2019
        foreach ($for_insert as $insert_item) {
            if ($modelName == 'Interest') {
                foreach ($insert_item as $item) {
                    $interest = new $model;
                    foreach ($item as $field => $value) {
                        if ($field != 'meta') {
                            $interest->$field = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    $interest->created_by_id = auth()->user()->id;
                    $interest->created_by_team_id = $request->input('church_id');
                    if (!empty($interest['lastname']))
                    {
                        $interest->save();
                    }
                    // For some reason, created_by_team_id was null on initial save, do it again
                    $interest->created_by_team_id = $request->input('church_id');
                    if (!empty($interest['lastname']))
                    {
                        $interest->save();
                    }
```

So in this manner, the system goes through the process of importing all the rows in the csv whether they have data or not but it only saves those records that have a lastname value. This accomplishes what I need but I know there must be a cleaner way to do it.

I believe there should be a method of doing this in which a record should be skipped only if all the values in a row/record is empty. So if one value is in place it will insert and create an entry but if all the values in a row are empty it will skip entry. Hopefully, someone will come along sometime and provide that more eloquent solution.